# Save data created in OpenCart 2.3 event for later display

Tags: opencart

I see how to use an event to generate a controller call in OpenCart 2.3.

What I don't see is how to save the data created by the controller call for later use in a view.

How have other people handled this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do here but couldn't you just do something like:

```
file_put_contents(DIR_CACHE . __CLASS__ . __FUNCTION__ . md5(serialize($this->request->get)) . '.ser', serialize($data));
```

That would store everything in `$data` (which is everything that gets passed to the view) in a flat file named after the class and method and query parameters.

Then, for example, to recall later on a product page, just do:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_CACHE . __CLASS__ . __FUNCTION__ . md5(serialize($this->request->get)) . '.ser') {
    $data = unserialize(file_get_contents(DIR_CACHE . __CLASS__ . __FUNCTION__ . md5(serialize($this->request->get)) . '.ser'));
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/product', $data));
}
```

Not sure if that answers your question but could could also just use Opencart's built in cache methods if you wanted it to expire at regular intervals.

Comment: If two users visited the same store at the same time, one would overwrite the other's cache data.

Comment: not necessarily.  that would depend on how and when you decide to write to the cache which is beyond the scope of what he asked

Comment: OK - "would" should have been "could".  Since this is a risk, it wouldn't be a good choice for the web.  If this was a desktop situation, yes, what you're suggesting would work.